# How to load and set rules in ace editor from file?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to set rules from external files, but since request is asynchronous, i can't find the way to make it work... any help appreciated.

```
window.define = window.define || ace.define;

define('ace/mode/myCustomMode', function(require, exports, module) {

var oop = require('ace/lib/oop');
var TextMode = require('ace/mode/text').Mode;
var Tokenizer = require('ace/tokenizer').Tokenizer;
var TextHighlightRules = require('ace/mode/text_highlight_rules').TextHighlightRules;

var myCustomRules = function() {
    this.$rules = {};
};

oop.inherits(myCustomRules, TextHighlightRules);

var Mode = function() {
    this.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer();
};
oop.inherits(Mode, TextMode);

d3.json('rules.json', function (error, data) {

    var myCustomRules = function() {

    this.addRules(data);


};
Mode.$tokenizer = new Tokenizer(new myCustomRules().getRules());

});

exports.Mode = Mode;
});
```

Comment: From your question, it is not clear what the issue is. What error do you see, what code do you use to load into ace, In which file is the above code snippet defined

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/w11mck0PPCui0QRVBhlG?p=preview

Comment: If you want to have mode and rules in different files, you need to use require.js or some other solution for module loading.

Comment: the problem is i can't load rules from json file

Comment: You need to have `data` already loaded when calling getRules(). addRules function is for something else. Also the json in demo is malformed.